# Ошибка с проектом Android в Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, вконтакте

Скачал данные [исходники](https://github.com/thest1/Android-VKontakte-SDK).

Закинул в Еклипс, выдает такие ошибки:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
> Unable to resolve target 'Google
> Inc.:Google
> APIs:21'  AndroidVkSdkSample      Unknown Android
> Target Problem The type
> java.lang.Object cannot be resolved.
> It is indirectly referenced from
> required .class
> files MainActivity.java   /AndroidVkSdkSample/src/com/perm/kate/api/sample    line
> 1 Java Problem The project was not
> built since its build path is
> incomplete. Cannot find the class file
> for java.lang.Object. Fix the build
> path then try building this
> project   AndroidVkSdkSample      Unknown Java
> Problem

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: @Nasdomlan, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Установите API 21. Он же явно сообщает, что не нашел Google APIs:21.